# Selenium WebDriver - how to return first word of text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

A first and last name are returned on the success page.  Both of the following methods return the Last Name back the data file.  How can I get the First name to be returned as well?  Something is wrong in my first method 'getMemberFirstName'.
There is no id, name, or class to the field.

```
 public String getMemberFirstName(){
     String mbrFirstName= "";
     int indx;
     page.waitForTextToLoad("has been successfully added");
     mbrFirstName = page.getFieldTextBy(By.cssSelector("form[name=AddCustomerForm] font"));
     indx = mbrFirstName.indexOf(" "); //Isolate First Name from other text in field
     mbrFirstName = mbrFirstName.substring(indx).trim();
     System.out.println("First Name: " + mbrFirstName);
     return mbrFirstName;
 }

 public String getMemberLastName(){
     String mbrLastName= "";
     int indx;
     page.waitForTextToLoad("has been successfully added");
     mbrLastName = page.getFieldTextBy(By.cssSelector("form[name=AddCustomerForm] font"));
     indx = mbrLastName.indexOf(" ")+1; //Isolate Last Name from other text in field
     mbrLastName = mbrLastName.substring(indx).trim();
     System.out.println("Last Name: " + mbrLastName);
     return mbrLastName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
 mbrFirstName = mbrFirstName.substring(0, indx).trim();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html